# Can I assign multiple keyword arguments to one value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, keyword-argument

I have a program that uses a function with a lot of keyword arguments that all default to `None` and was hoping that there was a better way than just assigning each one. This is the function declaration:

```
def __init__(self, includes=None, main=None,
                   functions=None, classes=None,
                   lambdas=None, variables=None,
                   values=None):
```

As you can tell, this is rather long and I was hoping there is something like

```
def __init__(self, includes=main=functions=classes=lambdas=variables=values=None):
```

which is much shorter and easier to write.

Can anyone answer this? It would be really helpful.

Comment: I don't think you can do that, at least I've never seen it

Comment: This is a time where it's likely better to use `**kwargs**`.

Comment: You syntactically can't. Function keyword arguments are comprised of a series of `keyword_items` that take the form `name = value`.

Comment: What do you dislike about `**kwargs` that makes you want something else?

Comment: What is your problem with the current syntax?  Is it the amount of typing involved?  The amount of space it takes?

Comment: @aryamccarthy it just doesn't seem specific enough

Comment: `def __init__(self, includes=main=functions=classes=lambdas=variables=values=None):` seems *less* readable to me.

Comment: @aryamccarthy it allows for more unexpected arguments that would include more proof-checking (which I detest)

Comment: 9000's answer shows how to restrict the domain. The syntax you describe does not exist in Python.

Answer (score 4):

You plainly can't, it's a syntax error.

Consider using `**kwargs` instead, as @aryamccarthy suggests.

You can check that you accept only names you want:

```
def foo(**kwargs):
  known_args = set(['pizza', 'burger', 'sausage'])
  extra_args = set(kwargs) - known_args
  if extra_args:
    raise ValueError('Unknown argument names: %r' % extra_args)
  # proceed as normal
```

Answer (score 2):

I mentioned in a comment that this is when you should really prefer `**kwargs`. It's a dictionary that catches all the named arguments you pass to the function. Here's how you'd use that:

```
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    if includes in kwargs:
        do_something()
    if main in kwargs:
        do_something_else()
    ...
```

Handle each argument the same way you'd normally use this:

```
if includes is not None:
    do_something()
if main is not None:
    do_something_else()
...
```

What you've asked about is not syntactically possible (and nothing *similar* exists), but this achieves the same *semantic* result.

Answer (score 0):

You could set a new variable to equal `None`, and then use that:

```
a = None
def __init__(self, includes=a, main=a, functions=a, classes=a, lambdas=a, variables=a, values=a):
```

Which would shorten it significantly, otherwise, no it is not possible.